# Free shipping for the amount over X USD

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

If I need to offer free shipping for a total cart amount over USD X, I tried this condition under Marketing --> Cart Price Rules in Magento 2.

[image: Rule]

This rule does not work because it seems that an item should be above USD X amount for it to work.

The conditions dropdownlist shows this:

[image: Choosing rule]

As you see, the attribute is per item. How can I do that so that the rule is for the cart total ?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: You can add from action tab there is option for subtotal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are my condition to have free sipping in UE
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I did not know conditions can be combinated. If the condition is already created as ANY with all the regions. Is it possible to add an ALL condition above it or do I have to start all over again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set condition in condition tab. There you will find cart attribute.

Comment: I have added the condition in Conditions tab but it did not work. In Actions tab there is a dropdown whose label is "Free shipping". If I set it to No, it always adds the shipping cost, even when the condition is true. If I set to any other option in that dropdown, shipping is always $ 0. What else could I try?

Comment: Delete your rule. Create a new one. In condition tab set "If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :" and than set "Subtotal  greater than" whatever you want. Than in Action set Free shipping. But first of all RTFM https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-free-shipping.html

Comment: Hello... the problem is that I cannot do that because the condition should not be "ALL" but "ANY". The fact is: store administrador has some states configured. The free shipping is only for determined states. Other states, shipping has a cost depending on the distance. Condition should be something like this: (Customer State = A OR Customer State = B OR Customer State = C and so on) AND Cart Total >= 60,000... is it possible to specify a condition such as that?